# How to have Gnome-like ALT + TAB window manager?

Tags: macos, keyboard, applications, window-manager

1. In Gnome using ALT + TAB you get a window manager to navigate to the child windows of Firefox or Google Chrome:

   [image: Gnome window manager]
2. In macOS holding CMD + press TAB gives similar window manager but you cant navigate to the child window's of Firefox or Google chrome:

   [image: macOS app switcher]

Is there any similar macOS tool like Gnome's?

I hear https://bahoom.com/hyperswitch but not sure if it's like Gnome. Is there some more similar so that I can pick up the best similar and share the experience.

Answer (score 1):

OSX 10.12.6 with third party app: https://bahoom.com/hyperswitch/get
Following is possible.

[image]

Comment: Couple other application switcher options: [Witch](https://manytricks.com/witch/), [Contexts](https://contexts.co/) (This one doesn't have a window preview though). As a bonus, there's a third party Dock replacement called [uBar](https://brawersoftware.com/products/ubar) - Has a window preview.

Comment: @Joonas neither witch nor contexts cannot do window previews. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Actually, it is funny that there is no solution to do such a simple thing on Mac OS

Comment: @igor, _Witch_ does have window previews. _Hyperswitch_ also has previews, as suggested by the author of this answer. Both of them do the previews a little differently. I think the _[Mission control](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204100)_ feature in mac (formerly: _Expose_) is part of the reason why this feature isn't on high demand.

Comment: @Joonas I was wrong indeed. though Witch previews are a little useless, HyperSwitch does it more like Gnome switcher. Just missed an option somehow. Thanks!

Comment: @Joonas but HyperSwitch misses another useful feature like hiding applications which don't have windows :(

Comment: @igor, I remembered a third app that I know to have previews. [SuperTab](http://www.supertab.me/). It's a bit different from other application switchers. I should mention that each section of the application switcher has its own settings, which you won't find in the application settings. Honestly though, if Witch previews aren't good enough for you, I don't think SuperTab will be any better. It handles previews sort of similarly. You can make a section in it that shows all application windows, which shows a thumbnail preview and when you hover over the thumbnail, it'll show a bigger preview.

Comment: Some applications have a "faceless mode" or "dockless mode" or simply "show application icon in the Dock" checkbox in the settings. If the app icon is not visible in the dock, it won't be in the application switcher. — I feel I should also add, in case you aren't aware, the Mission control I mentioned earlier can also show all the windows of the currently active app if you press the Mission control button while holding down `Ctrl`. That isn't exactly the same as seeing the window preview in the application switcher, but may be useful if you tend to have a lot of windows open.

Comment: @Joonas yep, but unfortunately, not all the applications have that dockless mode, or some of them don't work great in that mode (like iTerm)